# How to install my app as system app using system signature

Tags: android, apk

I am newbie to android and even to stack overflow. I created one sample application and it is running fine, .apk file is get created. Now my question is how to prepare it for publishing. i know there is many sites which explains this.
Like http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html
 I am little confused i want sign my app using system signature of emulator. I means i want install it as a system app. please help me..

Comment: you need to hack to device manufacture's network and get their key

Comment: why do you want to do that ?

Comment: If I have to develop an app for manufacturer how should I do that? Like some support app which the user should not uninstall. I have access to manufacture's network and their key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install your app as a system app due to security. In order to do this, you would need to make a custom ROM, install your app as part of the ROM and distribute the ROM. Not a particularly easy thing to do.

You haven't said why you need it to be a system app, but may be making the app a device administrator maybe more along the lines of what you are after. Below is the link for more details about making your app a device administrator.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply... Yes, I agree with you. But I want to develop an support app for the manufacturer which the user should not unistall!!!!!...

Comment: Its still not possible. Unless you come to some agreement with the Manufacturer of the device to embed your app into the their ROM, a manufacturer is highly unlikely to agree to do that. There's no way around it you have to install the app as part of the ROM